# Custom border radius bug. Material tailwind, Select element

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

That's how the Select behaves.

[image][image]

npm:

```
@material-tailwind/react: 2.1.2, 
tailwindcss: 3
```

Code:

```
<Select
  className="!border-[var(--orange)] !rounded-[var(--secondary-select)]"
  label={label}
  animate={{
    mount: { y: 0 },
    unmount: { y: 25 },
  }}>
  {options.map((option, i) => {
    return <Option key={i}>{option}</Option>;
  })}
</Select>
```

I have no idea how to fix that default border above select, please help.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that it's because of label:after, label:before border property.
[image]

So, I'll rewrite css properties for that.

---

```
 <Select
          className="border-[var(--orange)] rounded-[var(--secondary-select)]"
          labelProps={{
            // see also global css -> .secondary-select
            className: "after:border-none before:border-none",
          }}
          label={label}
    ...
```

.secondary-select is a class for the  wrapper.
add to the global.css:

```
.secondary-select button[aria-expanded="true"] ~ label {
  background-color: white;
  width: fit-content;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
.secondary-select button[aria-expanded="true"] ~ label::after,
.secondary-select button[aria-expanded="true"] ~ label::before {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
}
```